# SQL Query returning too many results

Tags: mysql

I have an sql query that is almost right but when a user has more than 1 aircraft in the database they end up with multiple row listings in the results returned from:

```
SELECT  a.this_pay, 
    u.username, 
    u.user_id, 
    c.type_id,
    c.is_primary, 
    x.typename, 
    p.pf_city, 
    p.pf_state, 
    n.username AS non_username, 
    n.user_id AS non_user_id, 
    n.pf_city AS non_pf_city, 
    n.pf_state AS non_pf_state 
    FROM (((((jowner_event_attendees a 
    LEFT JOIN jowner_users u ON a.user_id = u.user_id) 
    LEFT JOIN jowner_aircraft c ON a.user_id = c.user_id) 
    LEFT JOIN jowner_aircraft_types x ON x.id = c.type_id) 
    LEFT JOIN jowner_profile_fields_data p ON a.user_id = p.user_id) 
    LEFT JOIN jowner_not_users n ON a.user_id = n.user_id) 
    WHERE a.event_id = 28 ORDER BY COALESCE(u.username,non_username);
```

I end up with a list that has multiple entries for anyone with multiple aircraft, I only want 1 entry returned no matter how many aircraft entries they have in the 'jowner_aircraft' table.

I also would prefer to not change this query drastically as other parts of the app rely on it, obviously it needs the revision I am asking for, but please try to answer it without a complete rewrite.

Comment: Seeing a subselect like that is never a good thing. Can't this be written as a single `SELECT` call with joins?

Comment: I am working from other people's mediocre code, the problem is the app is reliant on this and so I am hesitant to change it too much...If you can come up with a query that is structured better and works for me then post it up :D

Comment: If there are multiple jowner_aircrafts, which aircraft typename and type_id should be selected?

Comment: Though it's off-topic, but what you need all these parentheses for?  Unless I'm missing something, they do not change a thing.

Comment: @femtoRgon - I have revised the question with the field to select which aircraft to include (c.is_primary == 1)

Comment: Could you possibly provide some sample data (or even better, `SQL Fiddle`) and the exact desired result?

Comment: @DrCord - What happens when you add `AND c.is_primary = 1` to your `JOIN` expression?

Comment: @ PM 77-1 - exactly what I needed, see answer I have accepted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.this_pay, 
    u.username, 
    u.user_id, 
    c.type_id, 
    x.typename, 
    p.pf_city, 
    p.pf_state, 
    n.username AS non_username, 
    n.user_id AS non_user_id, 
    n.pf_city AS non_pf_city, 
    n.pf_state AS non_pf_state 
    FROM (((((jowner_event_attendees a 
    LEFT JOIN jowner_users u ON a.user_id = u.user_id) 
    LEFT JOIN jowner_aircraft c ON a.user_id = c.user_id AND c.is_primary=1) 
    LEFT JOIN jowner_aircraft_types x ON x.id = c.type_id) 
    LEFT JOIN jowner_profile_fields_data p ON a.user_id = p.user_id) 
    LEFT JOIN jowner_not_users n ON a.user_id = n.user_id) 
    WHERE a.event_id = 28 ORDER BY COALESCE(u.username,non_username);
```

Comment: Thanks! I know that the refinement of my question due to an insightful question helped this solution, thanks to femtoRgon for his help!

Comment: Although, I doubt c.is_primary==1 is really what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Would a

```
SELECT
a.this_pay, 
u.username, 
u.user_id, 
c.type_id, 
x.typename, 
p.pf_city, 
p.pf_state, 
n.username AS non_username, 
n.user_id AS non_user_id, 
n.pf_city AS non_pf_city, 
n.pf_state AS non_pf_state 
FROM (((((jowner_event_attendees a 
LEFT JOIN jowner_users u ON a.user_id = u.user_id) 
LEFT JOIN jowner_aircraft c ON a.user_id = c.user_id) 
LEFT JOIN jowner_aircraft_types x ON x.id = c.type_id) 
LEFT JOIN jowner_profile_fields_data p ON a.user_id = p.user_id) 
LEFT JOIN jowner_not_users n ON a.user_id = n.user_id) 
WHERE a.event_id = 28 ORDER BY COALESCE(u.username,non_username)
LIMIT 1;
```

be out of the question?

A bit of clarification would help, such as what this query is ultimately designed to do. If it was originally designed to return multiple rows and you're needing it to serve another purpose, it stands to reason you should give it a nice clean overhaul.

Comment: it should never return multiple rows as it is showing a list of event attendees, I did a bit of hackery to add in the aircraft lines: "LEFT JOIN jowner_aircraft c ON a.user_id = c.user_id) 
LEFT JOIN jowner_aircraft_types x ON x.id = c.type_id) ", they seemed to work fine, but now I am finding they don't quite...

Comment: I think I understand. You're left joining on your aircraft table, so naturally it's going to turn each row of "owner information" which happens to own multiple aircraft into multiple rows. You should consider using a sub-select if you require only a single row of their aircraft info "jowner_aircraft" and "jowner_aircraft_types", because it's going to want to grab all of them. Otherwise you will need to do some functional concatenation, or something else "different".

Comment: OP tagged his question with **MySQL**. Even if getting a single record as the result of the entire query was required (and it does not seem to be a case) you would need `LIMIT 1`, as `TOP 1` is specific to SQL Server.

Comment: yeah, I understand why it isn't working, thanks for the confirmation though. What I need is an example of something that might/will work, as I have been trying sub-selects of various types with only errors all afternoon...

Comment: @ Tony - thanks though, each user response helped me to think it through and refine what I wanted, I love Stack Exchange! :D

Answer (score 0):

You should just need to add another where clause to eliminate all but the record where is_primary is true.

```
SELECT  a.this_pay, 
u.username, 
u.user_id, 
c.type_id,
c.is_primary, 
x.typename, 
p.pf_city, 
p.pf_state, 
n.username AS non_username, 
n.user_id AS non_user_id, 
n.pf_city AS non_pf_city, 
n.pf_state AS non_pf_state 
FROM jowner_event_attendees a 
LEFT JOIN jowner_users u ON a.user_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN jowner_aircraft c ON a.user_id = c.user_id 
LEFT JOIN jowner_aircraft_types x ON x.id = c.type_id
LEFT JOIN jowner_profile_fields_data p ON a.user_id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN jowner_not_users n ON a.user_id = n.user_id 
WHERE a.event_id = 28 
AND c.is_primary = 1
ORDER BY COALESCE(u.username,non_username);
```

Substituting whatever the correct value for "true" is for is_primary.

Comment: That actually didn't work and had the side effect or resorting the list of attendees that is returned.

Comment: Didn't notice the `order by` clause the first time.